# Probability and balls

Tags: probability, statistics

An urn contains four blue balls and three white balls. A second urn contains five blue and four white balls. Pass up a ball from the first to the second urn and then extracted a ball second urn. How likely to be white?

If the result is blue ball, what is the probability that the first recession resulted white ball?

I tried:

- if the ball is white -probability of being White in the second is $\frac12$ we can have this 3 times
- else, the probability of being white is $\frac25$ we can have this $4$ times

So probability of being white is $\frac12\cdot \frac37=\frac{3}{14}$?

If we get one blue and the firt one was white... we could get $\frac{3}{14}\cdot \frac12 = \frac3{28}$.

Comment: The title of this question sounds like a good night in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made quite a couple of mistakes, but the actually, you only made one crutial mistake: You did not go about your problem systematically. You throw a lot of numbers around, but I advise you that you rather spend more time thinking about which number goes where. It will help you solve more difficult tasks further on.

OK, let's start from the beginning. We have a two-step process. In the first step, one of the two events occurs: $H_1$ is the event "a white ball is taken from the first urn", and $H_2$ is the event "a blue ball is taken from the first urn."

It is fairly obvious that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are mutually exclusive and cover the whole space of possible events, i.e. $\{H_1,H_2\}$ is a **partition** of the space of possible events in the first step.

Then, in the second step, we want to know the probability of the event $X$ which is "a white ball is taken from the second urn" .

You can write the probability of $P(X)$ as

$$P(X) = P(X|H_1)\cdot P(H_1) + P(X|H_2)\cdot P(H_2)$$

Now, you simply need to calculate the probabilities, which you already did, and plug them into the equation on the correct places (which you did not).

Comment: P(H1)= 3/7 and  P(H2)=4/7  OK. P(X|H1)=3/7*(1/2+2/5) and P(X|H2)=4/7*(1/2+3/5)?

Comment: @JeanDennis How did you get $P(X|H_1)$? Remember, $P(X|H_1)$ is the probability that you will draw a white ball from the second urn **after** you already draw a white ball from the first urn.

Comment: P(X|H1)=  If the first was not white, 4/7 multiplied by 4/10 (the probability of being white). If it was, 3/7 multiplied by 5/10 (the probability of being white). So, P(X|H1)=  4/7 *4/10 +3/7*5/10 ?

Comment: @JeanDennis What you wrote is the formula for $P(X)$, not $P(X|H_1)$, but yes, you are correct!

Comment: the probability of being blue is 39/70... because it is 1-(31/70)=39/70. If the first is white the probability is 3/7. So If the result is blue ball, the probability that the first recession resulted white ball is 39/70*3/7?

Comment: @JeanDennis I have no idea what you just asked. What recession?

Comment: the probability of being blue is 39/70... because it is 1-(31/70)=39/70. If the first is white the probability is 3/7. So If the result is blue ball, the probability that the first removed resulted white ball is 39/70*3/7? –

Comment: @JeanDennis I don't know because you did not tell me what question you are answering... The answer to the question in your original post is $\frac{31}{70}$, but you seem to have moved on to another question without telling me what the question is. If you have another question, then accept this answer and ask a new question on the site.

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote in the question above ""if the result is blue ball, what is the probability that the first "removed" resulted white ball?""  After asking "How likely to be white?"

Comment: @JeanDennis I advise you to ask a new question on the site and accept my answer on this one. It will be cleaner that way.

Comment: No, you understood it in the wrong way: your answer is right.... look at what I asked before I said hat I tried...in the original question... It was "two" question... like letter a and b... I did not change the question now.

Comment: But I wrote recession instead of "removed"

Comment: @JeanDennis I understand completely. But if you have a two part question, that's really two questions. It is cleaner to ask it that way because if I try to answer your question in comments, it will get messy.

Comment: Ok. I am sorry. Thanks!!